# Raspberry Pi Asynchronous/Continuous Speech Recognition in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition

I want to create a speech recognition script for the Raspberry Pi in Python and need an asynchronous/continuous speech recognition library. Asynchronous means that I need endless running of the recognition until the spoken matches to an array of words without any input from a keyboard, and then display the spoken to the terminal and restart recognition. I already had a look at PocketSphinx, but after a few hours Googling, I didn't find anything about an Asynchronous recognition with that.

Do you know any Library who is capable of that?

Comment: You mean like Jasper?

Comment: Yes, but maybe (if possible) without a keyword (Is jasper the project with the keyword or do I mix it up)

Comment: And if possible, it would be great if it would work without an internet connection, but its not necessary

Comment: See [here](http://jasperproject.github.io/) for more.

Comment: Yes, I already had a look at that, but would it be possible to give jasper a array of keywords, and then perform actions without first listening to the keyword "jasper"?

Comment: Well, you can change Jasper's [name](http://jasperproject.github.io/) perhaps to something else. Perhaps, even an empty string.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Pocketsphinx on Raspberry Pi. You need to download latest version 5prealpha.

It can listen for multiple keyphrases. The code should be something like this:

```
import sys, os
from pocketsphinx import *
import pyaudio

modeldir = "../../../model"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-kws', 'keyphrase.list')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

# Process audio chunk by chunk. On keyword detected perform action and restart search
decoder = Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    if decoder.hyp() != None:
        print "Detected keyword", decoder.hyp(), "restarting search"
        decoder.end_utt()
        decoder.start_utt()
```

The `keypharse.list` file should look like this, one phrase per line with threshold

```
open the door /1e-40/
close the door /1e-40/
how are you /1e-30/
```

Thresholds must be tuned for every keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misdetections.

Comment: Jasper is much easier derivate of PocketSphinx.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can change Jasper's [name](http://jasperproject.github.io/) perhaps to something else. Perhaps, even an empty string.

Comment: Just so you know you only need to say Jasper's name once, so it shouldn't be much of an inconvenience, as you would still need to boot the Pi and enter your username and password. Personally, I'd stick with the name and take the extra second of setup time.

Comment: Don't you have to say the name once after every comment?

Comment: No just once per session.

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow and if it works, I'll accept your answer, OK?